# E11 is blocking execution of htc files when set to Deny all add-ons unless specifically allowed in the Add-on List policy is set

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I maintain an older web app where .htc files are used to provide almost all functionality (more on what are .htc files here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532146(v=vs.85).aspx).

the problem I have is, that once I enable **Deny all add-ons unless specifically allowed**... policy, I can't get my web page run .htc files (some are downloaded but not executed).

I suppose I should enable as second step some COM objects via their GUIDs in the **Add-on List** in the first row but I tried to add all plugins on my machine my IE loads, without any luck (I expected that one of those MS related plugins will provide functionality of running .htc files/objects).

this is what I see in my Local Group Policy Editor setting
[local group policy editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTdFk.png)

I made a simple demo to test if htc files will be executed (if you don't have such page/demo on your box) : https://github.com/rostacik/htciesample

I saw some how-to's for disabling loading of JS, Flash, etc. so I suppose there is some object that is responsible for .htc files.

my setup: latest win 10 pro with 1803 update, OS build 17134.1, IE 11 v 11.1.17134.0, update versions 11.0.47.
the very same behavior is with Win7 Enterprise with latest IE11.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

With **Deny all add-ons unless specifically allowed**, you have to enable the **Add-on List** and then add there two GUIDs:

- **{F414C260-6AC0-11CF-B6D1-00AA00BBBB58}**
- **{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}**

both with value **1**.